# For what values of $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sqrt{2^k+k^2}$ has integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for a rule giving integer solutions of:
$$x=\sqrt{2^k+k^2}$$
for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
I found a solution for $k=6$, but I'm unable to find a general formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$k=0$ and $k=6$ are the only solutions. If $x^2=2^k+k^2$, then $2^k=x^2-k^2=(x+k)(x-k)$. This implies that 
$$x+k=2^{k-t},\quad x-k=2^t,$$ 
for some integer $t\leq k/2$. We find $\,2k=2^{k-t}-2^t$. It's easy to see that the last relation can holds only for few values of $k$. Infact 
$$2k=2^{k-t}-2^t=2^t(2^{k-2t}-1)>\max\{2^t;2^{k-2t-1}\},$$ then
$$16k^3=(2k)^2\cdot4k>2^{2t}\cdot 2^{k-2t}=2^k$$
The last inequality cannot be true for $k$ too large (particularly for $k>17$). So you only have to handle by hand the remaining cases, and you find that the only solutions are $k=0$ and $k=6$.

Comment: Unfortunately I found $\sqrt{2^{64}+64^2}=4294967296$ which is integer.

Comment: Hmm...$2^{64}=(2^{32})^2$ and $(2^{32}+1)^2-2^{64}=2^{33}+1>64^2$, so how can $\sqrt{2^{64}+64^2}$ be a square??

Comment: $2^{64}+64^2=2^{64}+2^{12}=2^{12}(2^{52}+1)$ but $2^{52}+1$ ends in a $7$ so it's not a square. Maybe you ran into round-off error.

Comment: However, $k = 0$ is a second solution ;)

Comment: Yeah :) I edited my answer, thank you!

Comment: @Capublanca: can you explain why if $2^{33}+1\gt 64^2$, $\sqrt{2^{64}+64^2}$ can't be a square please?

Comment: $2^{64}$ is the square of $2^{32}$. The successive square is $(2^{32}+1)^2$, and it's bigger than $2^{64}+64$